# clearfix technique adds some extra padding

Tags: html, css

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/119/)**

Using `clearfix technique` is awesome useful but anyone has indicated the problem of using this method is increased extra padding value as shown in demo.

**The height of both are equal.**

CSS:

```
body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#wrap{width: 900px; height: 250px; background: red; margin: 0 auto;}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{content: "."; display: table;}
.clearfix:after{clear: both;}
.clearfix{zoom: 1;}
#box{float: left; width: 200px; height: 250px; background: blue;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
<div id="box"><h1>some heading text here</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Paste code of clear fix

Comment: [:before pseudo-element prevents top-margin collapse](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a Jakub said.
`.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{content: "."; display: table;}` is adding a period before and after your element.  Rather, use this code:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{content: " "; display: table;}
```

Or, another method is to only use this code:

```
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: No need even for the space (it solves an [Opera+contenteditable bug](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)). Empty string is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is simply this:

```
.clearfix:before
```

If you add that it will stick a `.` in front just like you are setting in your CSS a `.`
Remove it and it works fine with `clearfix:after`